# What does "MU-TH-UR" stand for?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

In the movie *Alien* the ship Nostromo has in it a computer which the crew refer to as "mother". In looking that up I found that "mother" is actually the [MU-TH-UR 6000](https://alienanthology.wikia.com/wiki/MU-TH-UR_6000), but I have been unable to find what "MU", "TH" and "UR" stand for.

What does "MU-TH-UR" stand for?

[image: MU-TH-UR inscription on panel]

Comment: MU = Mainframe Unit?

Comment: According to that Wikia article, it was “2.1 terabyte” (I assume hard-drive); so perhaps TH = Terabyte Harddrive?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it doesn't stand for anything. There was also a FA/TH/UR in the 4th Alien film.

Comment: I don't believe there is a canon answer to what MU-TH-UR stands for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The acronym is undefined according to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_computers),

> MU-TH-R 182 model 2.1 terabyte AI Mainframe/"Mother", the ship-board
>   computer on the space ship Nostromo, known by the crew as 'mother,' in
>   the SF horror movie Alien (cf Dark Star, above, which used a similar
>   name and was co-written by the primary writer of Alien) (1979)